# Making use of all of the CPU power serving a queue - but not too much

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cpu-usage

Consider a queue of jobs with multiple consumers, I want to write an application in **C#** which takes out a job at a time and do it. The queue resides on a separate server and I might have to run multiple instances of my application to keep the queue served on time.

I believe the best practice would be to use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh195051.aspx) to ensure the maximum power of consumer's CPU is used. In this implementation, main thread is polling the queue, once a job is available it is dequeued, then tended to in a different thread using `Task.Run`.

My concern is that, since once a consumer dequeues a job, it is out of other consumers' reach, is it possible that a consumer takes in too much jobs while others are free, in the sense that if the jobs were distributed differently (more evenly) they would be done sooner altogether? Do I need to worry about such a scenario or not?

If my concern is real, then how can I control it in C#?

Comment: Seems to me that applying a Producer-Consumer design pattern is a way to go. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: That's true but as far as algorithms go, computational power is of no concern.

Comment: Distributing work over multiple processes running on multiple machines is never a minor implementation detail.  You need to fret over getting the load balanced, the data and results shuttled back and forth and ensure that random failure of a client doesn't bring the house of cards down.  This is the job of a server, never of a client.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you saying that jobs need to be pushed to clients, not pulled? Do you know of such a server, preferably open source? Added information: in my case jobs come with with a date indicating when they should be executed.